# freeing the same memory with distructors

Tags: c++

I try to free the memory correctly after the program ends, but I always encounter a problem.

In my code I want to have an array of all the numbers that I allow in my program, and have objects A and B (or more) that each one have some of the numbers that I allowed.

In the end I want to delete 'a' and 'b' only after "ints" getting out of the scope. But A and B calls their distructors to delete some of ints variables.

```
#define MAX_LEN 255

class IntArray
{
    public:
        int len;
        void add(int* n) {
            arr[len] = n; len++; 
        }

        IntArray() : arr(new int* [MAX_LEN]), len(0) {}
        ~IntArray() {
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                delete arr[i];
            delete[] arr;
        }
    private:
        int** arr;
};

class Object
{
    public:
        void add(int* n) { 
            myIntArr.add(n); 
        }
    private:
        IntArray myIntArr;
};

int main(void)
{
    int* a = new int(5);
    int* b = new int(6);

    IntArray ints;
    ints.add(a);
    ints.add(b);

    Object A;
    A.add(a);

    Object B;
    B.add(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share dynamically allocated `int`s between multiple objects, use `std::shared_ptr<int>`.

Also, rather than writing a dynamic array type yourself, use `std::vector` to do it (correctly) for you.

```
using int_ptr = std::shared_ptr<int>;

class IntArray
{
    public:
        void add(int_ptr n) {
            arr.push_back(n);
        }

    private:
        std::vector<int_ptr> arr
};

class Object
{
    public:
        void add(int_ptr n) { 
            myIntArr.add(n); 
        }
    private:
        IntArray myIntArr;
};

int main(void)
{
    int_ptr a = std::make_shared<int>(5);
    int_ptr b = std::make_shared<int>(6);

    IntArray ints;
    ints.add(a);
    ints.add(b);

    Object A;
    A.add(a);

    Object B;
    B.add(b);

    return 0;
}
```

If you just want to have a copyable array of `int`, use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>;` - a 1D array of shared integers rather than a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

You're deleting `a` and `b` twice.
You should only delete something returned by `new` and exactly once.

But you add them both to `IntArray ints;` and then one each to `Object`s `A` and `B` and their destructors delete them also. Destructors are called in reverse order to it's when `ints` is destructed you'll be deleting them again - that's "Undefined Behaviour" but normally a catastrophic failure (crash) either immediately or later during executon.

The shortest fix is:

```
int* a = new int(5);
int* b = new int(6);
int *ac = new int(*a);//copy of *a
int *ab = new int(*b);//copy of *b


IntArray ints;
ints.add(a);
ints.add(b);

Object A;
A.add(ac);

Object B;
B.add(bc);
```

But it's not clear what our intention is. `IntArray` isn't an array of `int` as it stands, it's an array of pointers to int (which have been allocated by `new`).

My 'fix' will mean if you modify `a` (e.g. `*a=20`) you won't modify the copy (`ac`) added to the `Object A`.

Comment: I need to be able to change the values inside ints somewhere in the code, and I want them to be changed also inside A and B.

Comment: @user1473213 In which case my 'fix' won't work. If you're using C++11 or later your simplest solution is to use `std::shared_ptr<int>` that is a relatively lightweight object that will keep track of (count) the number of 'shared' pointers and delete the value when the last `shared_ptr` is destructed.